# My script is returning an undefined error in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

Here is the JS and HTML code:

```js
function dateChange(){
  var e = document.getElementById("trainingtype");
  var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var val = str;
  if (val == "1"){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class2");
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class3");
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("datepicker").value="Select Date and Place";
  } else {
    //another If else statement
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="item_name" id="trainingtype" onChange="dateChange()">
  <option selected>Select training type</option>
  <option value="Bike">Bike Riding</option>
  <option value="Bucket">Bucket Washing</option>
  <option value="Shoe">Shoe Tying</option> 
</select>

<select name="datepicker" id="datepicker" onChange="amountChange(value)">
  <option>Select Date and Place</option>
  <option class="class1" value="1">1</option>
  <option class="class2" value="2">2</option>
  <option class="class3" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but does not work in Microsoft Edge. In the console I get the error: `SCRIPT5009: 'value' is undefined`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What line of code produces the error?

Comment: Is it possible that `e.selectedIndex` is undefined, which you're using as an index to then try to pull a `.value` property from an array?

Comment: I suspect the value access on "datepicker". Does a select control really have a settable value property?

Comment: @Mark No, it's not: https://twitter.com/SampsonMSFT/status/690247661534863361

Comment: @Sampson: On the other hand, IE still works better with dynamic SVG. Edge is sadly unusable there (or at least our scenarios run into a bunch of showstopping bugs).

Comment: @Sampson, thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: @Joey Please share examples/repros. I'll fast-track them to our engineers.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send you private message with the link and brief problem description?

Comment: @Sampson: Thanks for the offer. The issues we face are all on connect already somewhere. I'll see whether I can dig them up tomorrow at work. They were mostly related with text rendering, especially with dashes and transforms; also disappearing text at times and sometimes not repainting properly, leaving ghosts. Some of the more text-heavy [demos](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.3/demos/complete/demo.yfiles.graph.bpmneditor/index.html) exhibit that, but we also had a few minimal repro cases worked out.

Comment: @Joey Please feel free to take advantage of the access I can provide :) Connect will eventually deliver the feedback, but I'll be able to do so within a matter of minutes in most cases.

Comment: @Joey BTW, that demo seems to produce ghosts on Firefox Nightly too

Answer (score 2):

The following line of JavaScript doesn't call the element you're expecting:

```
var e = document.getElementById("trainingtype");
```

This is calling the `#trainingtype` element, which is this:

```
<select name="item_name" id="trainingtype" onChange="dateChange()">
    <option selected>Select training type</option>
    <option value="Bike">Bike Riding</option>
    <option value="Bucket">Bucket Washing</option>
    <option value="Shoe">Shoe Tying</option>    
</select>
```

You then go on to test the vlaue:

```
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var val = str;
if (val == "1") {
```

However, *1* is not similar to any value in the list of options. The original list of options has been replaced, but they weren't numbers. They were words/phrases.

It seems like, instead, you meant to call `#datepicker` (which has values like *1*, *2*, and *3*). Otherwise, perhaps you unintentionally used the wrong value types in your first option list.

Comment: sorry for val == "1" it's my mistake. In real code val is compared with string value, which is listed in options in select element

Comment: We cannot help if you make up the code as you go along :) Please post the *actual code* that you're running your browser, replacing any content that is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.